# SQL Query that returns n spaces

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query that returns n number of spaces(" ") that I need to
append I a fixed length file.

So far I have been able to create

```
select ' ' from dual connect by level < 254
```

this returns multiple records I need only one record with 253 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [LPAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm#OLADM593) function:

```
select LPAD(' ', 254, ' ') from dual connect by level < 254;
```

***p.s.***: if only one row is required use

```
select LPAD(' ', 254, ' ') from dual;
```

This pre-pends as many spaces `' '` to the String `' '` so the the returned value has a length of 254.

Comment: That still gives 253 rows back too.

Comment: yeah it does, but by removing connect  by level I got single row with 253 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work:

```
select rpad(' ', 254)
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

> select ' ' from dual connect by level < 254

Just for some fun! You could have made *your* query *working* too, without **LPAD**. Using string aggregation, like **LISTAGG**:

For example,

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT ' ' str FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 254
)
SELECT listagg(str, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY str) str FROM DATA;
```

You can check the **length** to see how many spaces it created:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT ' ' str FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 254
  3  )
  4  SELECT LENGTH(listagg(str, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY str)) str FROM DATA;

       STR
----------
       253
```

Though this also gives the desired output, it was just for fun, the appropriate way is to use **`LPAD`**.